# I install the gst module in odoo10 and expected the use taxes in accounting. But there have some issues related installing module

Tags: accounting

I want to install my gst module in odoo10. If I have install module so I have got the error.

Here's the error:

```
ParseError: "Field names must be unique per model.None" while parsing /home/dhiraj/workspace_10/gst_10.0/l10n_in_gst/data/ir_model_fields_data.xml:23, near
```

Here's the code:

```
<record model="ir.model.fields" id="company_gstin_field">
    <field name="name">x_gstin</field>
    <field name="field_description">GSTIN</field>
    <field name="help">GST Identification Number</field>
    <field name="ttype">char</field>
    <field name="related">partner_id.x_gstin</field>
    <field name="size">15</field>
    <field name="state">manual</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_company"/>
</record>
```

Comment: I think the gstreamer tag is wrong - gstreamer is a multimedia framework.